# How to make a responsive image grid which changes image size depending on the amount of images?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I'm trying to make a responsive grid of images which makes the images smaller when there are multiple next to each other and larger when there is, for instance, only one image.

*(For better understanding here below are some photos of expected results)*

**Photo 1:**

[image]

**Photo 2:**

[image]

I've tried playing with the max-width and min-width and using various display modes but no luck. Furthermore, I've tried looking on the internet but no luck there too.

```css
.photos .content {
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.photos .content .grid {
  display: overflow: none;
}

.photos img {
  max-width: 30%;
  min-width: 25%;
  height: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel photos">
  <div class="content" id="photos">
    <div class="grid">
      <img src="img/sample-images/sample1.jpg">
      <img src="img/sample-images/sample2.jpg">
      <img src="img/sample-images/sample3.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For starters, `display: overflow: none;` is invalid. Display and overflow are two separate properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that there are 3 images on first row and 3 in second row.

Don't give width of the image as 30%, instead give it 100%

So that it will reduce the size as per the viewport

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns : repeat(3,1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 20vw);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid_image {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
}
```

[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/subin_s/pen/KYgxWX)

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS in the parent container

```css
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:repeat( 3 (no. of images), 1fr );
```

If you keep on adding images next to it, it will automatically adjust on that first row